# Grab Last Name for User ID in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to figure out how to grab a userID's last name attribute but not sure how. I have tried to look at some examples but are falling short. Below is what I have so far but want to either get the last name attribute separately or grab the display name (which is first.last) and pull all the information after the period. Please help

```
Import-Module activedirectory

#$userID = Get-Aduser -filter *
$userIDs = Get-Aduser "w35522"


foreach ($lastName in $userIDs) {

$lastname = (get-Aduser -Filter * -Properties displayname).lastname 

}

write-host $lastName
```

Update:

Thanks to comment below I changed lastname to surname. Only issue is now it prints the OU too which I don't want.

```
Import-Module activedirectory

#$userID = Get-Aduser -filter *
$userIDs = Get-Aduser "w35522"


foreach ($user in $userIDs) {

$lastname = get-Aduser -Identity $userIDs -Properties * | Select-Object name,     GivenName, SurName, DisplayName

$user.SurName

write-host $user


}
```

prints: 
    Weyers
    CN=w35522,OU=Standard,OU=Users,OU=Corporate,DC=we,DC=dirsrv,DC=com

FINAL UPDATE:

ok figured it out. It needed to say write-host $lastname instead!

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property which is returned by default that you are looking for is `surname`. That being said you have other logic issues in your script.

```
Get-ADUser someuser| select surname
```

Once in the loop you do another `Get-Aduser`. Also you assign a value to `$lastName` which is the pipe object you should be attempting to access.

If you really wanted all the lastnames in the company you would do something like this.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * | Select-Object Surname
```